# Trying to launch a partial function as a result of an if statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to launch a partial function as a result of an if statement but I can't get it to work.

Here's the code causing a problem:

```
class chrono:
    def stop_chrono_gauche(chrono, event):
        chrono.Stop()

    def stop_chrono_droit(chrono, event):
        chrono.Stop()

[...]

if(GPIO.input(17) ==1):
    partial(stop_chrono_gauche, (sw))

if(GPIO.input(21) ==1):
    partial(stop_chrono_droit, (sv))
```

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: Do you have a traceback? or which is the error?

Comment: I don't have any errors, but the fonction isn't being launched

Comment: Just creating a partial function and doing nothing with it isn't very useful. You have to store it somewhere and then call it at some point to get any effect. (Well, you could also just call it immediately, but at that point, there's no reason to use partial; you can just call the function directly.)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Because your code as written doesn't really make enough sense to guess what you want to happen in that `if` statement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Whatever you're trying to do, `partial` has nothing to do with any solution to that problem, so asking how to use `partial` is not going to get you a useful answer.

Comment: @technorevolutionary GPIO.input is part of a library in the raspberry pi

Answer (score 1):

The function isn't being called because you never call it; you just create a partial function and then do nothing with it.

If you just want to call `stop_chrono_gauche` in the `if` statement, just call it, without using `partial`.

If you want to create the `partial` function and store it somewhere to be called later, then you have to actually store it somewhere and call it later.

Comment: the fonctions are in a class so I can't call them

Comment: @Mranth0ny62 Do you need to call them?

Comment: yup, the GPIO are connected to sensors and I want the timer to stop when they're crossed

Comment: but how do you call a partial stored in a variable

Comment: @Mranth0ny62: If you can't call the functions because they're in a class, you also can't make partials out of them for the exact same reason. And the way you call a partial stored in a variable is the same way you call any other callable: just `variable(argument, argument)`. I don't think you understand what `partial` actually does, so you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Mranth0ny62: Also, in your example above, the functions are _not_ in a class. So please edit your question to give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually demonstrates the problem you're stuck on, rather than something completely different.

Comment: well the thing is, this is not my code and I only know the bare minimum in python (I'm working in a group and the guy working on this part isn't doing much so I need to do his part), so that's why I don't understand a lot

Comment: @MranthOny62: if you can't even explain what you want to do or why you think you should be using partial here, nobody can tell you how to do what you want with partial. I don't know how to help you any further here with what you've told us. Maybe your coworker, who presumably knows this code and knows what he wants you to do with it, can help, but I doubt anyone else can unless you can give us more.